# Can't catch any DOM element for fireevent Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am facing issues when I try to run the test cases using jest.

Error:-

```
 Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element.
```

console:-

```
`If I try using queryByTestId it gives console as` :- "null"

 `If I try using getElementsByClassName it gives console as`:- "HTMLCollection {}"
```

Code:-
TableHead Componet

```
const TableHead = ({
  checkHeaderState,
  headers,
  isCheckBox,
  selectAllChecked,
  sortColumn,
}) => {
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState(COR_TABLE.DESCENDING);

  const checkRef = useRef();

  const handleSorterChange = (dataIndex, sortDirection) => {
    const updatedsorterState = getsorterState(sortDirection);
    setSortOrder(updatedsorterState);
    sortColumn(dataIndex, updatedsorterState);
  };

  return (
    <thead className={`${mainClass}__tableHead`}>
      <tr className={`${mainClass}__headerRow`}>
        {headers.map((item, i) => {
          const { header, key, ref, style, sortable } = item;
          return (
            <Fragment key={i}>
              <th ref={ref} className={`${mainClass}__sortable`} style={style}>
                {isCheckBox && i === 0 && (
                  <input
                    id="selectAllCheckBox"
                    className={`${mainClass}__checkBox`}
                    type="checkbox"
                    onClick={selectAllChecked}
                    ref={checkRef}
                  />
                )}
                <span>{header}</span>
                {sortable && (
                  <Icon
                    id="sortIcon"
                    className={`${mainClass}__sort-icon`}
                    icon={SortIcon}
                    color={"midnightblue"}
                    height="16px"
                    onClick={() =>
                      handleSorterChange(key.toLowerCase(), sortOrder)
                    }
                  />
                )}
              </th>
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </tr>
    </thead>
  );
};
```

I have imported this component in my `TableWrapper` component.

Test file:-

```
   it("Select all checkBox to be clicked", () => {
    // const onChangeSpy = jest.spyOn(TableWrapper.prototype,"selectAllChecked")
    const { container } = render(<TableWrapper {...props} />);
    const checkBox = container.getElementsByClassName("oct-cors-TableWrapper__tableHead");
    console.log("asdsa", checkBox)
    // fireEvent.click(checkBox);
    // expect(checkBox).toBeChecked()
    const inputElement5 = container.find('.oct-cors-TableWrapper__tableHead .oct-cors-TableWrapper__headerRow .oct-cors-TableWrapper__sortable .oct-cors-TableWrapper__checkBox');
    
    // let inputElement = container.getElementsByClassName(".oct-cors-TableWrapper__tableHead .oct-cors-TableWrapper__headerRow .oct-cors-TableWrapper__sortable .oct-cors-TableWrapper__checkBox")
    // inputElement.simulate("click");
    console.log("dsadaseee",inputElement);
    // expect(inputElement).to.have.length(1);
  });
```

Tried accessing the click on `checkbox` and `sortIcon` but was not able to reach

2nd option tried:-

```
const { queryByTestId } = render(<TableWrapper {...props} />);
    const checkBox = queryByTestId("sortIcon");
    console.log("asdsa", checkBox)
    fireEvent.click(checkBox);
```

I am trying to click on `checkBox` and fire click event on `sortIcon`

TestFile Imports

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import TableWrapper from "./TableWrapper";
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?
Can someone suggest me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `queryByTestId("sortIcon")` query will look for an element with `data-testid="sortIcon"` which you don't have. Try adding `data-testid="sortIcon"` to your `Icon`.